# MacBook Pro; Remote Desktop; External and built in screen

Tags: mac, remote-desktop

I am using Remote desktop connection on my 2017 MacBook Pro.   I go back and forth between using the built in screen and connecting to an external monitor.   How can I have the screen resolution change depending on the monitor being used?   I either have a small screen on my larger monitor, or a oversized screen on the built in monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Get the beta RDC - though it's been in beta about 2 years now, it's a lot better than the release version
[MS Technet - Remote Desktop Client Preview for Mac supports multiple monitors and more](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/)

It has a new option to 'Fit session to window' rather than the old one you had to pick a screen resolution. I haven't tested how it work across different sized monitors, as both mine are the same size.

[image]